# How would i stop sound from playing? -Java

Tags: java, audio

This is the code im using to play sound and it works perfect for my needs. I just dont know how i can stop a clip from playing when i want it to.

```
public class Sound {

    public Clip play(String filename) {
        Clip clip = null;

            try {
                File file = new File(filename);
                AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioIn);
                clip.stop();
                clip.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return clip;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at JavaDocs for [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) you should note that one of the inherited methods from `DataLine` is `stop`

> Stops the line. A stopped line should cease I/O activity. If the line
>   is open and running, however, it should retain the resources required
>   to resume activity. A stopped line should retain any audio data in its
>   buffer instead of discarding it, so that upon resumption the I/O can
>   continue where it left off, if possible. (This doesn't guarantee that
>   there will never be discontinuities beyond the current buffer, of
>   course; if the stopped condition continues for too long, input or
>   output samples might be dropped.) If desired, the retained data can be
>   discarded by invoking the flush method. When audio capture or playback
>   stops, a STOP event is generated.

You may need to verify this, but I seem to understand that `start` is a blocking method, that is, once called, to will not return until the `Clip` finishes playing.  This would require the `Clip` to be started in a separate `Thread`